# how to secure a json file to host on a server

Tags: javascript, json, error-handling, laravel-8

I created several json files and hosted on an online server; I want secure sorting only when a client wants to perform a get on the files; we can check if it is authenticated before. I made the authentication system with laravel.

in the routes/api.php I put this

```
Route::middleware('auth:sanctum')->get('/user', function (Request $request) {

   Route:: get('https://jsonfile.ubix-group.com/lecons/lecon1.json');

});


Route::post('api/inscription', [AuthController::class, 'InscrisUtilisateur']);

Route::post('api/connexion', [AuthController::class, 'connexion']);
```

but I still manage to access the links even if I haven't logged in.